# Why am I not allowed to answer this question

Tags: support, bug

I would like to provide a new (much easier to use) answer to this question: [Audible DRM Removal for personal use](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105821/audible-drm-removal-for-personal-use)

Unfortunately, I can't, due to this error message:

> Thank you for your interest in this question. Because it has attracted low-quality or spam answers that had to be removed, posting an answer now requires 10 reputation on this site.

I wonder why I cannot answer the question, even though my reputation is (right now) 108, which definitely is over 10?
I know that 100 of those reputation points are a transferral from other sites of the Q&A network, but from what I know these are explicitly to allow trusted users to skip the barriers for new users (like this one), so it does not make sense to me that they apparantly are not being counted.

Comment: I pushed you over 10 points excluding the bonus, can you try if you can answer now?

Comment: Zulakis never did answer the question, it seems.

Answer (score 5):

There's a long running feature request to [improve the wording of the protection notice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210481/improve-protected-question-message-with-regard-to-rep-gained-through-associati). TL;DR: The association bonus **does not** count for protected questions. IMO it might be clearer if you read the notice this way: You have to earn 10 rep on *this site*. The 100 you get is a freebie from other sites.

The intention is to ensure that you have at least some degree of familiarity with the site.

Comment: And with the addition of "([the association bonus does not count](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user))" (complete with explanatory link), this is probably [meta-tag:status-completed].